# c++ segmentation fault when deleting dynamic tables

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

everyone I have to make a dynamic matrix and here are the constructors and destructor I have:

```
Board::Board() {
    a_l=0;
    a_c=0;
    a_mp=NULL;
}
Board::Board(const Board&t) {
    a_l=t.a_l;
    a_c=t.a_c;
    a_mp=t.a_mp;
    Memory();
    copy(t);
}
Board::Board(int nl, int nc) {
    a_l=nl;
    a_c=nc;
    Memory();
}
Board::~Board() {
    freeMemory();
}

// PRIVATE METHODS

void Board::copy(const Board &t) {
    int a_l, a_c;
    int ** a_mp;
    a_l=t.a_l;
    a_c=t.a_c;
    for(int i=a_l;i<a_c;i++) {
        for(int j=a_c;j<a_l;j++) {
            a_mp[i][j]=t.a_mp[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void Board::freeMemory() {
    for(int i=0;i<a_l-1;i++) {
        delete [] a_mp[i];
    }
    delete [] a_mp;
}
void Board::Memory() {
    char ** a_mp;
    a_mp = new char*[a_l];
    for(int i =0;i<a_l; i++) {
        a_mp[i]=new char[a_c];
        for(int j=0;j<a_c;j++)
            a_mp[i][j]='-';
    }
}
```

Board is the class and a_l and a_c are number of lines and columns of the matrix. In my main, I declare a Board variable and then I do this:

```
board=Board(5,5);
```

It compiles, but when I want to display it, like this for example:

```
cout << board.Cols() << endl;
```

This is the method:

```
int Board::Cols() const {
    return (a_c);
}
```

It displays 0. As if it didn't create board with the parameters I said.
Also the program crashes when I do this `board=Board(5,5);` so I use the debugger and it says it stops at this line of the delete:

```
board=Board(5,5);
```

I don't know why it crashes and I don't know why it doesn't keep the values of the board variable I've declared!
Anyone knows why?

EDIT: rMemory=Memory, it was a type from here not from the program

Comment: Show us implementation of the `Memory()` function.

Comment: show your code for Memory()

Comment: board=Board(5,5); wouldnt work, this is c++, instead Board board = new Board(5,5); what types are a_c and a_l?

Comment: They are both int. @tacp, Memory=rMemory, it was a typo copying the code

Comment: @Infested, "_board=Board(5,5); wouldnt work_" - Why?

Comment: @soon first off, he didnt declare its type (or he didnt mention it), secondly to dynamically allocate space you use new.

Comment: @Infested, 1) "_I declare a Board variable_" - so, type of `board` is `Board`, I guess, not `Board*`. 2) Why are you using dynamic allocation in that case?

Comment: @soon the title is dynamic tables. actually, if an object is instantiated not dynamically then its destructor is built in. since you coded this class, and you dont know whats going to be in it when you start the program you allocate it

Comment: @Infested, dynamic table is a class member.

Comment: @soon well that explains. in freeMemory watch for how you delete, i know that its very strict with how it should be written with arrays. delete[] != delete []

Comment: @Infested, I see no differences between `delete[]` and `delete []`, do you?

Comment: @soon i know that theres a difference, check it yourself.

Comment: @Infested, do you want to talk about it in chat?

Comment: @soon no problem, link please!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28446/discussion-between-soon-and-infested)

Comment: Note: Don't add "solved" and "thank you" to the question once answered. That's what the answer checkmark and upvotes are for.

Comment: just updating here my answer about delete[] vs delete []: delete is a token
the tokenizer (when building the project) is looking for tokens
since delete [] is delete space []
it counts delete as a token, then [] as a token
whilst delete[] is another token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this assignment

```
board=Board(5,5);
```

is over-complicated. You can just declare

```
Board board(5,5);
```

directly (the extra work may well be optimized out, but it's un-idiomatic).

---

Secondly, everywhere you do something like:

```
void Board::copy(const Board &t) {
    int a_l, a_c;
    int ** a_mp;
```

you're *shadowing* the object's member variables. That is, `a_l` now refers to the local integer variable inside this function, instead of the object member. You'll have to refer to `this->a_l` if you want to see or change the object.

---

Now, the copy constructor

```
Board::Board(const Board&t) {
    a_l=t.a_l;
    a_c=t.a_c;
    a_mp=t.a_mp;
    Memory();
    copy(t);
}
```

does:

1. a *shallow* copy (it shares the `a_mp` pointer with the object you're copying)
2. calls `Memory` which allocates a *new* lump of memory, referred to as `a_mp` only inside `Memory`, and then leaked (when that local variable goes out of scope)
3. calls `copy`, which copies the original objects values into an *uninitialized* local pointer also called `a_mp` (this is undefined behaviour, because those writes could go anywhere)
4. ends up with the value of `a_mp` it first chose, so now *two* `Board` instances have the same `a_mp` value, and it will be freed twice.

---

Here's some sample code that fixes those problems: I've changed the structure of your code as little as possible (bar renaming things for readability). There's plenty of room for improvement, but it should at least be correct.

```
class Board {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    char **data;
public:
    Board(): rows(0), cols(0), data(0) {}
    Board(int nl, int nc) : rows(nl), cols(nc) 
    {
        allocate_data();
    }
    Board(const Board& other)
        : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols)
    {
        allocate_data();
        copy_data(other);
    }
    ~Board() {
        free_data();
    }
private:
    void copy_data(const Board &other) {
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++)
            for(int c=0; c<cols; c++)
                data[r][c]=t.data[r][c];
    }
    void free_data() {
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++)
            delete [] data[r];
        delete [] data;
    }
    void allocate_data() {
        data = new char*[rows];
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++) {
            data[r]=new char[cols];
            for(int c=0; c<cols; c++)
                data[r][c]='-';
        }
    }
};
```

Note that this works fine if you *only* use the copy constructor, but the default-generated assignment operator will still be wrong. As Daniel Weber pointed out in a comment, the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) suggests you ought to write this as well:

```
    Board& operator=(const Board& other) {
        free_data();
        rows = other.rows;
        cols = other.cols;
        allocate_data();
        copy_data(other);
    }
```

Note that the copy assignment operator needs to cope with a destination object which is already initialized, and may not have the right dimensions. You could improve this to only re-allocate if the new (`other`) board is larger.

If you have C++11 support, you can also add the *move* equivalents of the copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
    Board(Board&& original)
        : rows(original.rows), cols(original.cols)
    {
        data = original.data;
        original.data = NULL;
    }
    Board& operator=(Board&& original) {
        free_data();
        rows = original.rows;
        cols = original.cols;
        data = original.data;
        original.data = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you fixed my second problem !

Comment: This answer lacks the Rule of Three (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). The problem of the missing assignment operator is bypassed by using the constructor instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
int ** a_mp;
```

Needs to be just `a_mp`. Otherwise **you are declaring a new variable**. Instead of using the member one.

And then it needs to be allocated to. right now it is not.

---

```
void Board::copy(const Board &t) {
    int a_l, a_c;
    a_mp = new char[t.a_l][t.a_c];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // a_l=t.a_l; These have already be done in the copy constructor. 
    // a_c=t.a_c;
    for(int i=a_l;i<a_c;i++) {
        for(int j=a_c;j<a_l;j++) {
            a_mp[i][j]=t.a_mp[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

---

or if you want you can allocate it in the copy constructor

```
Board::Board(const Board&t) {
    a_l=t.a_l;
    a_c=t.a_c;
    // a_mp=t.a_mp;  // This is wrong!!
    a_mp = new char[t.a_l][t.a_c];
    copy(t);
}
```

Comment: But I need to make a copy of the actual object, thats why I have the method copy

Comment: @p.bosch Yes you need the copy() to copy the data. That didn't change. I commented the column and row assignments because you have already done them in `Board::Board(const Board&t)`before you call copy()

Comment: I've done this, but now I'm getting 2 errors on the line a_mp = new int[t.a_l][t.a_c]; which are 't' and '.' cannot appear in constant-expression. What do they mean?

Comment: @p.bosch how did you declare a_mp in the class?

Comment: These are the attributes in the class:     private:
        int a_l;
        int a_c;
        char ** a_mp;

Comment: @p.bosch the matrix is char? Oh :) I will edit the answer. I just assumed it was int. And if you can please edit and put the errors on the question.

Comment: @user2280716 I automatically changed that when trying it out and it didn't work out. Salgar has solves my crashing problem but values still don't get saved, any idea?

Comment: @p.bosch yes remove `a_mp=t.a_mp;` from `Board::Board(const Board&t)` and remove `int ** a_mp;` from `Board::copy(const Board &t)`

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i=0;i<a_l-1;i++)` in `freeMemory` runs from `i=0` to `i=3`, which is the last i that is < `5-1`.
You are missing one line since your allocation Loop runs is `for(int i =0;i<a_l; i++)` and therefore runs from `i=0` to `i=4`. You allocate one more line.

Another thing is: What does copy() do? You copy the values of t.a_l and t.a_c to temporary variables which are deleted once copy ends and you assign values to unallocated Memory (the temporary **a_mp).
Remove the declaration and assignments within this function and only leave the a_mp data copy.

```
void Board::copy(Board const &t) {
    for(int i=a_l;i<a_c;i++) {
        for(int j=a_c;j<a_l;j++) {
            a_mp[i][j]=t.a_mp[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

What i did:

- Remove the declaration of a_mp in `Memory()`
- Add a Assignment Operator -> [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
- Check for NULL-pointer in the freeMemory() function

Looks like this:

```
class Board
{
public:
  int a_l, a_c;
  char ** a_mp;

  Board() : a_l(0), a_c(0), a_mp(NULL) 
  {
  }
  Board(const Board&t) : a_l(t.a_l), a_c(t.a_c), a_mp(NULL) 
  {
    Memory();
    copy(t);
  }
  Board(int nl, int nc) : a_l(nl), a_c(nc), a_mp(NULL) 
  {
    Memory();
  }

  Board& operator= (Board const &t)
  {
    freeMemory();
    a_l = t.a_l;
    a_c = t.a_c;
    Memory();
    copy(t);
    return *this;
  }

  Board::~Board() 
  {
    freeMemory();
  }

  // PRIVATE METHODS

  void copy(const Board &t) 
  {
    for(int i=a_l;i<a_c;i++) 
    {
      for(int j=a_c;j<a_l;j++) 
      {
        a_mp[i][j]=t.a_mp[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  void freeMemory() 
  {
    if (a_mp == NULL)
    {
      for(int i=0;i<a_l;i++) 
      {
        delete [] a_mp[i];
      }
      delete [] a_mp;
    }
  }
  void Memory() {
    a_mp = new char*[a_l];
    for(int i =0;i<a_l; i++) 
    {
      a_mp[i]=new char[a_c];
      for(int j=0;j<a_c;j++) a_mp[i][j] = '-';
    }
  }

  int Cols() const 
  {
    return (a_c);
  }

};
```

Works.

```
Board testboard;
testboard = Board(5,5);
cout << "Cols are: " << testboard.Cols() << endl;
```

Prints: "Cols are: 5".

Answer (score 1):

```
void Board::Memory() {
    char ** a_mp;
    a_mp = new char*[a_l];
    for(int i =0;i<a_l; i++) {
        a_mp[i]=new char[a_c];
        for(int j=0;j<a_c;j++)
            a_mp[i][j]='-';
    }
}
```

You're declaring a local variable on the stack called a_mp. This pointer points to all of the allocated memory on the heap. Then it goes out of scope at the end of the call to Memory(). Now you have no way of accessing any of that memory you just assigned. This is sad. a_mp should be a a member variable, so that you still have a reference to your data after Memory finishes. And so that your destructor knows what memory to free.

i.e. Remove this line: `char ** a_mp;`

Comment: May I also suggest that you remove the copy and the copy constructor functions, and just get it working with the normal constructor first. i.e. write `Board foo(5,5); foo.cols(); foo.stuff(); foo.anything_else();` and make sure it also exits cleanly without crashing. Then afterwards add the copy function. As you have so many different errors here apparently. I just dealt with the first one.

Comment: Yes! It works. But I'm still getting the second error: cout << board.Cols() << endl; This doesnt display the actual columns, it displays 0. I'm calling it right after the board=Board(5,5)

Comment: @p.bosch try this function without the const in the end of it.

Comment: @Infested If you meant board.Cols() I tried it but no difference, still doesn't save the values.

Comment: This is the same problem for your copy() function. Remove `    int a_l, a_c;` and make sure they are members and Cols() will work. Otherwise, stop using the copy constructor, and it will work if you declare your variable like I did above.